# Does a return in a thread lamda do anything?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have some code that works something like this

```
std::vector<std::thread> threadList;
threadList.emplace_back(
    []() {
        doWork();
    }
);
```

Would adding `return;` in the lambda change anything about how the program executes, for example:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threadList;
threadList.emplace_back(
    []() {
        doWork();
        return;
    }
);
```

I tried both of them and I can't tell a difference, but I'm wondering if there is any.

Comment: It has the same effect as in any function: none.

Answer (score 2):

There is an implicit `return` statement at the end of a `void`-returning function, therefore both pieces of code have identical semantics.